# Appcenter causes crash in release config

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-app-center

I have a xamarin ios app that has been functioning well in debug mode, But after I bundle and sign the app for the store, and install it in testflight, the app crashes at startup.

So, what I did was run the code in VS in release mode, with dev provisioning profiles.
I discovered appcenter crashed the app at runtime.

I've tried a lot of things, I saw [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/troubleshooting/xamarin) stating I should update my xamarin iOS components to 10.4.0.128 or later,
Since my app was targeting version 10 of iOS, I targeted version 11 in the info.plist.
But it still didn't work. Could someone help ? please

Here is the error I got from appcenter:

```
error: Failed to load AOT module 'Microsoft.AppCenter.iOS.Bindings' while running in aot- 
only mode: doesn't match assembly.

Failed to load AOT module 'Microsoft.AppCenter.iOS.Bindings' while 
running in aot-only mode: doesn't match assembly
=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a abrt while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
     Native stacktrace:
=================================================================
0x10811def0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_dump_native_crash_info
0x10811415c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_handle_native_crash
0x10811d43c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_runtime_posix_install_handlers
0x1f071b298 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>
0x1f0720b50 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib : pthread_kill
0x1ae09fb74 - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib : abort
0x10795f770 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/MyApp.MobileApp.Ios : xamarin_find_protocol_wrapper_type
0x1080eae70 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : monoeg_g_logv
0x1080eaec0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : monoeg_g_log
0x1080f3b58 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_aot_init
0x108153ba0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_assembly_invoke_load_hook_internal
0x108154cb8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_assembly_request_load_from
0x1081547c4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_assembly_request_open
0x108156d48 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_assembly_open
0x107967160 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/MyApp.MobileApp.Ios : xamarin_log
0x1081574f8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_assembly_loaded_internal
0x108156974 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_assembly_request_byname
0x1080fcc54 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_aot_get_method_flags
0x1080f4144 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_aot_init
0x108153ba0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_assembly_invoke_load_hook_internal
0x108154cb8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_assembly_request_load_from
0x1081547c4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_assembly_request_open
0x108156d48 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Mono : mono_assembly_open
0x10795ed78 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/MyApp.MobileApp.Ios : xamarin_get_block_descriptor
0x10434b5d0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/MyApp.MobileApp.Ios : _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy
0x107966e50 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/MyApp.MobileApp.Ios : xamarin_log
0x10434b97c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/BF008523-C9AE-4E16-B9FC-0C818F485D55/Myapp.MobileApp/MyApp.MobileApp.Ios : _ZN7plcrash2MS5async24dwarf_cfa_state_iteratorIyxE4nextEPjPNS1_28plcrash_dwarf_cfa_reg_rule_tEPy
0x1a48a66b0 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>

=================================================================
  Basic Fault Address Reporting
=================================================================
```

Memory around native instruction pointer (0x1d2bc6414):0x1d2bc6404  ff 0f 5f d6 c0 03 5f d6
10 29 80 d2 01 10 00 d4  ..*...*..)......
0x1d2bc6414  03 01 00 54 7f 23 03 d5 fd 7b bf a9 fd 03 00 91  ...T.#...{......
0x1d2bc6424  ff 71 ff 97 bf 03 00 91 fd 7b c1 a8 ff 0f 5f d6  .q.......{....*.
0x1d2bc6434  c0 03 5f d6 90 29 80 d2 01 10 00 d4 03 01 00 54  ..*..).........T

```
 =================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
 =================================================================
 =================================================================
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem, have you fixed that?